# Raycast 2d is not working in Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I'm new to Unity and blocked 2nd day with a simple try to raycast. This is the script which I use to raycast:

```
void Update () {
    Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, transform.position - transform.up);
    RaycastHit2D[] hits = Physics2D.RaycastAll(transform.position, transform.position - transform.up, Mathf.Infinity);
    if(hits.Length > 0)
    {
        Debug.Log("Hit");
    }
}
```

I have attached this script to a square and put near it another square which acts like a target, also added a 2d box collider to the target. I have disabled the "hit itself" feature like is described here:
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/756380/raycast-ignore-itself.html 
After performing all this steps the raycast hits nothing, the collider of the hit object is always null (checked this in debug mode, also nothing is written in console) . I drew a debug line, and indeed it points to the target square like in screenshots. 
[image]
[image]

Please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: you are using a 2d raycast on a 3d box collider. you need to either use a 2d collider to match, or instead use a normal Raycast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Physics.Raycast` is for 3D Colliders and this includes Box Collider, Sphere Collider and others. No 2D in their names.

`Physics2D.Raycast` is for 2D colliders. You need a Box Collider 2D since this is a Sprite Renderer which is a 2D Object.

**EDIT**:

With your edit, the problem is that the direction of the raycast is too short. You have to multiply it by a number. The value of 100 should be fine.

```
public float distance = 100f;

void Update()
{
    Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, transform.position + transform.right);
    RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, transform.position + transform.right * distance, Mathf.Infinity);
    if (hit.collider != null)
    {
        Debug.Log("hit: " + hit.collider.name);
    }
}
```

Comment: I know about this, that's a screen from my desperate attempt to make it work... I forgot to put it back for the screenshot, sorry for that. So if it's a 2D collider it still doesn't work. Any other ideas what I'm missing?

Comment: In that case, update your screenshot with what you should have and I will update my answer. Make sure to add that EDIT in it.

Comment: I tried to start a new project from zero hoping that would solve my problem with no success :( . I attached the new screens and new modified script in which I'm trying to "raycastAll".

Comment: Thanks a lot. Multiplying by 100 fixed the problem. But I don't understand why I should do it. I thought I have to indicate the direction and it would go by max specified distance (Mathf.Infinity in my case) and would return the first collision point or null.

Comment: `Mathf.Infinity` is for internal physics system for how far the raycast should go from the provided direction. The problem is that the provided direction is too short. Take a look the `Debug.DrawLine`. You will see that it is too shot. Now, also change the second parameter of `Debug.DrawLine` to `transform.position + transform.right * distance`. You will see how long the line is.

Comment: Why is then the distance specified? According to docs it's max distance to cast the ray [https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.Raycast.html]. I tried to change it to 1, 0, -100 and it's still hits the collider. Isn't this parameter useless because I'm already specifying the max distance as a vector (second parameter) ?

Comment: Your 1,0,-100 test is flowed. I tried it with 0 and it did not detect anything like I said above. I tried it with 3 and it detected something but you have to go extremely close to the other object if you want it to detect something. You use the third parameter to control how much of the second parameter to use. Finally, you can actually use an actual direction like `Vector3.right` in the second parameter and you won't run into any issue at-all. The reason I didn't use it is because you want the ray to face the character direction.